# livewire return response code 302 on live server on subfolder

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have a component in the main layout and it working great. the problem is with the component using a different layout than the main one the requests to livewire return response 302 then redirect to login (only on the live server, working locally).

my main problem is that I don't know what is causing this issue. it just returns response code 302.

p.s.
this component doesn't have authentication
it's a simple form and it works fine on the local server but returns response code 302 then redirects to the login although it doesn't require authentication.

Comment: Show your code! Let's help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the problem was that the project wasn't in the root folder but in a subfolder. I moved it to a subdomain and it works correctly.